# Node js - error state of a callback in a loop

Tags: node.js, callback, google-cloud-messaging

I am using node js to send push notifications to Android devices using GCM and want to delete the device id if I get an error message from Google. The code snippet is attached and runs in a loop (i is number of device ids).

My issue is that if the call returns an error (err4), all future loops return if(err4) as true and all the ids after the first error are deleted. Why is the err4 not getting reset?

```
for(var i = 0; i < noofdeviceIds; i++){

// some more code here to create the 'message'.

(function(i) {
  gcm.send(message, function(err4, messageId){
    if (err4) {
    console.log("\nError occured: Notification could not be sent with error: ", err4);//
    if(err4 == 'NotRegistered' || err4 == 'InvalidRegistration'){
       console.log("\nRemoving the entry from the DB.");
        var removeEntryQuery = "DELETE FROM devicereg WHERE deviceregId = '" + deviceregIds[i] + "'";
    req._dbConnection.query(removeEntryQuery, function(err5, row) { 
        if(row!=0){console.log("\nDB returned: ", row);}
      });
    }
  }
else {
    console.log("\nMessage sent with message ID: ", messageId);
      }
});
})(i);
}
```

Comment: You're using `for` loop here? If so you have same scope variables here for all `i`

Comment: What library are you using for `gcm`?

Comment: @loadaverage : I have added the for loop in the code above. We have same scope variable, but my expectation was that err4 would get reset every time the new callback is called. Event setting err4 = 'null' did not help.

Comment: @bolav : I am using gcm - https://www.npmjs.com/package/gcm